# Getting 'GET' parameter in views.py

Tags: python, django, web

I am trying to get a 'GET' parameter from one of my template pages, called 'id' (ex. issues.html?id=1), and using it to perform a variety of retrievals from my sqlite database. However, when I run the following code, I get the error "'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'id'"

Here is some of my code in views.py:

```
def issues(request):
    # Retrive basic legislation details from GET parameter
    legislation_id = request.GET.id
    legislation = Legislation.objects.filter(id = legislation_id)[0]

    # Getter functions from database - names are pretty self-explanatory
    def get_buttons():
        button_html = ""
        for tag in legislation.demographic_tags:
            button_html += "<input type='button' class='button' onclick='showtag"+tag.hash_code+"();' value='"+tag.name+"'>"
        return button_html
    def get_description():
        return legislation.description
    def get_script():
        return ""
    def get_sponsor():
        return legislation.sponsor
    def get_summary():
        return legislation.summary
    def get_title():
        return legislation.name

    # Return results back to page
    return render(request, 'issues.html',
{'buttons': get_buttons(), 'description': get_description(), 'script': get_script(), 'sponsor': get_sponsor(),
'summary': get_summary(), 'title': get_title()})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be here: `legislation_id = request.GET.id`

[`request.GET`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET) is a dictionary so you need to get its key like this:

```
legislation_id = request.GET["id"]
```

You can also get the key with `dict`'s `get` method as @Alvaro suggested: `request.GET.get("id", 0)`. This will return `0` as default if `id` key ain't present and save you from `KeyError` exception.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I would recommend using request.GET.get("id"). It will return None in case the dict doesn't have the key instead of raising KeyError (or even a default: request.GET.get("id", 0)   )

Comment: @Alvaro you're right, although probably the whole view fails if the `id` is not there, your suggestion is very helpful. I'll include it.

Comment: @LordChiu consider accepting the answer if it was helpful so others can benefit from it too.